# Data binding to a dynamic path in Polymer

Tags: javascript, data-binding, javascript-objects, polymer-1.0, polymerfire

I am building a web app with Polymer 1.0 and Firebase, and I want to have the view change when data was entered into a path with a user ID in the path. To do that, I want to do something like this:

```
[[question.answers.(user.uid).choice]]
```

Let me explain in more detail. So, in the template, I have something like this:

```
 <ul id="question-list">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[questions]]" sort="_computeSort" as="question">
      <li class="card question" data-key="[[question.$key]]" question="[[question]]">
        <h3 class="content">[[question.question]]</h3>
        <p hidden$="[[ MY DATA BINDING HERE ]]">[[question.afterMessage]]</p>
      </li>
    </template>
  </ul>
```

If you look at the `<p>` element above, inside the `hidden` attribute is where I want to have my data binding to happen. The structure of a `questions` path is like this:

[image: questions data structure]

So `questions` is a collection of questions, and each question has a property `afterMessage`, which I want to show the user after answering the question.

In order to check if the user has answered the question, I have a path called `answers` within the `questions` path. Inside that `answers` path, I have the users's key as a key to the choice that the user chose.

So, if a user with user key of `ZjHDMDa270Uyp6sAL02Mam2ftGf2` is logged into my app, the data binding path to that user's answer would be:

```
[[quesion.answers.ZjHDMDa270Uyp6sAL02Mam2ftGf2.choice]]
```

Now this above expression is what I want to bind to, but of course the user ID changes from user to user, so how can I do this? In other words, I want to do something like this:

```
[[question.answers.(user.uid).choice]]
```

Comment: By the way, I have tried [[question.answers[ [[user.uid]] ].choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polymer data bindings don't support nesting or expressions. You would likely have to use a [computed binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#annotated-computed) like this:

```
// template's computed binding
[[_getChoice(question, user.uid)]]

// script
Polymer({
  _getChoice: function(question, uid) {
    return question.answers[uid].choice;
  },
  ...
});
```

Comment: If the property `choice` changes, either using `Polymer.Element.set` method or `Polymer.Element.notifyPath` method to notify it, your binding will not be updated.