# Polymer - How to bind a dynamic path?

Tags: polymer

How to bind a dynamic path in Polymer?

For instance:
Lets say our component has 2 properties:

1. `list`: an array of objects.
2. `map` : a javascript object which map sub-objects.

Each item in the list has a property `key` which is the key to get the value from the `map` property.
I would like to "dynamic" bind a path like `map[item.key]`. The only way to do something like this is to make a function, but it will not be triggered on changes of properties and sub-properties of map. =/

In the following snippet, you can see, by clicking on the button, it will dynamicly place an object in the `map.key2` property, using the `Polymer.Element.set` method. But this doesn't trigger any changes because Polymer doesn't bind a path. It only execute the display function once.
**So this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44077272/data-binding-to-a-dynamic-path-in-polymer) doesn't help (even though it's the same question)**.

```html
<script src="https://polygit.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="employee-list.html">
<link rel="import"  href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import"  href="https://polygit.org/components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import"  href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/lib/elements/dom-repeat.html">


<dom-module id="my-element">

 <template>
  <ul>
   <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[list]]">
    <!--Bind something like this-->
    <li> [[ _getAt(item.key) ]] </li>
   </template>
  </ul>

  <!--This button will add the 2nd object-->
  <paper-button on-tap="_onButtonClicked" raised>Add key 2</paper-button>
 </template>

 <script>
  class MyElement extends Polymer.Element {
   static get is(){
    return "my-element";
   }

   static get properties(){
    return {
     list : {
      type : Array,
      value : function () {
       return [
        {
         key : "key1",
         // ...
        },
        {
         key : "key2",
         // ...
        },
        // ...
       ]
      }
     },
     map : {
      type : Object,
      value : function () {
       return {
        key1 : {
         message : "Hello",
         // ...
        },
        // ...
       }
      }
     }
    };
   }

   _onButtonClicked(){
    // Add the 2nd object
    this.set("map.key2", {
     message : "World",
    });
        
     console.log("key 2 added");
   }
      
      _getAt(key){
        if (this.map[key])
          return this.map[key].message;
      }
  }

  customElements.define(MyElement.is, MyElement);
 </script>
</dom-module>

<my-element></my-element>
```

The [Polymer documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/model-data#specifying-paths) says that it's possible to build a path in a array. But I didn't find a way to bind an array of string as a path.

Answer (score 0):

> "The only way to do something like this is to make a function, but it
>   will not be triggered on changes of properties and sub-properties of
>   map"

You can make this work by passing the objects/properties that are changing.
Basic example

this will NOT update:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[_getItems()]]"></template>
```

this WILL update:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[_getItems(list)]]"></template>
```

Now the dom-repeat will fire again once the property 'list' changes.
Let's say you have 2 properties, and you want to re-run dom-repeat when one of them changes:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[_getItems(list, somethingElse)]]"></template>
```

You might also want to take a look at https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/model-data#override-dirty-check

EDIT:

Where are you updating the property LIST? dom-repeat wont run again until that property is changed

DOUBLE EDIT:

try this (polygit is currently having server issues):

```html
<script src="https://polygit.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="employee-list.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/lib/elements/dom-repeat.html">


<dom-module id="my-element">

    <template>
  <ul>
   <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[list]]">
    <!--Bind something like this-->
    <li> [[ _getAt(item.key, map, list) ]] </li>
   </template>
     </ul>

    <!--This button will add the 2nd object-->
    <paper-button on-tap="_onButtonClicked" raised>Add key 2</paper-button>
    </template>

    <script>
        class MyElement extends Polymer.Element {
            static get is() {
                return "my-element";
            }

            static get properties() {
                return {
                    list: {
                        type: Array,
                        value: function() {
                            return [{
                                    key: "key1",
                                    // ...
                                },
                                {
                                    key: "key2",
                                    // ...
                                },
                                // ...
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    map: {
                        type: Object,
                        value: function() {
                            return {
                                key1: {
                                    message: "Hello",
                                    // ...
                                },
                                // ...
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
            }

            _onButtonClicked() {
                var foo = this.list;

                this.set("map.key2", {
                    message: "World",
                });
               this.set("list", {});
               this.set("list", foo);
                console.log("key 2 added");
            }

            _getAt(key) {
                if (this.map[key])
                    return this.map[key].message;
            }
        }

        customElements.define(MyElement.is, MyElement);
    </script>
</dom-module>

<my-element></my-element>
```

Comment: You're are forcing the entire list to refresh. Thats realy not optimized. If that was my puspose, I would just set the `mutable-data` property on the array, and trigger the `notifyPath` method on the list.

Comment: Furthermore, I know this trick to pass objects as parameters to the method, becaise they are considered as dependency. But this doesn't help if the `map.key2.message` property changes. Neither for binding upward (using `{{path}}`) because bindong functions are only downward.